# Navigation Drawer color

Tags: java, android, colors, navigation, drawer

So, newbie here starting app development. I created an app with a Navigation Drawer with several fragments.

The NavDraw has a black background and I want the selected fragment to have a red background (to indicate what fragment is being shown). Right now, it doesn't give me any visual feedback of the fragment selected, the only feedback I have is when I touch the item in the nav drawer.

In the layout folder I have the `activity_main.xml` and several fragments (`fragment_one.xml`, `fragment_two.xml` etc). I guess the changes I need are going to be implemented in the activity_main, no?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your current code. It's hard to answer questions like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the folowing to your ListView:

```
android:listSelector="#FF0000"
```

So it will look like the following:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="#FF0000"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted and couldn't find!